How to properly handle observation data in Kotlin for Android
I have an application that retrieves data from a database. At the moment the data is being downloaded, a progressbar and text appear on the screen informing that the data is being downloaded. After the data is downloaded, the text and the spinner disappear. However, in some cases the application does not behave quite right. Sometimes the application freezes, sometimes the progressbar and text disappear but the data is not downloaded correctly. Have I implemented the code correctly?
Spinner is only for some default values to show at the beginning of the activity.
This is repository:
 fun getAllZebra(): LiveData<List<Int>>{
        return sybaseDao.getAllZebra()
    }

This is ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class ZebraViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: SybaseRepository
):ViewModel(){
    val skladnici = repository.getSkladnik().asLiveData()

    fun getAllZebra(): LiveData<List<Int>>{
        return repository.getAllZebra()
    }
}

and this is activity
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ZebraActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    //private val viewModel : ZebraViewModel by viewModels()
    var idZebra : Int = 0
    var idExp: Int = 0
    private val zebraViewModel: ZebraViewModel by viewModels()
    private val spinner3 by lazy {findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.zebra_spinner)}
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)        
        SybaseApi.initilaizeBaseUrl(this)
        val binding = ActivityZebraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)     

        binding.apply {
            zebraViewModel.skladnici.observe(this@ZebraActivity) { result ->
                val skladnici: List<Skladnik>? = result.data
                if (skladnici != null) {
                    Log.e("Skladnici", skladnici.size.toString())
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("Skladnici", "NULL")
                }
                progressBarLogin.isVisible =
                    result is Resource.Loading && result.data.isNullOrEmpty()
                textViewProgressBar.isVisible =
                    result is Resource.Loading && result.data.isNullOrEmpty()
                textViewProgressBar.text = "Loading data from database"
                textViewErrorLogin.isVisible =
                    result is Resource.Error && result.data.isNullOrEmpty()
                textViewErrorLogin.text = result.error?.localizedMessage
                textViewErrorLogin.isVisible = result is Resource.Success
                textViewErrorLogin.text = "Data uploaded:"
            }
        }

        
        

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        SybaseApi.initilaizeBaseUrl(this)
        initSpinnerData()
    }

    private fun initSpinnerData(){
        val allDevices = this?.let {
            ArrayAdapter<Any>(it, R.layout.simple_item_spinner, R.id.tv_simple_item)
        }        
        allDevices?.clear()
        zebraViewModel.getAllZebra()
            .observe(this, { devices ->
                devices?.forEach{
                    allDevices?.getPosition(it)?.let { it1 -> if (it1 < 0) allDevices?.add(it) }
                }
            } )
        spinner3.adapter = allDevices
        spinner3.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, position: Int, p3: Long) {
                if (parent != null) {
                    val idZebraString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                    idZebra = idZebraString.toInt()

                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ZebraActivity, "You need to choose some item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()            }

        }
    }

}


I think the problem is not with the Database but with the view, I see you are using Spinner with ArrayAdapter, are you using that data to feed the Spinner with ArrayAdapter? If yes, than can you check if you can use the RecyclerView.Adapter with it.

Actually, there is no problem with spinner, that spinner works fine.

Did you tried using Flow<> for fetching data, I mean with coroutines? Is your data size to large to load?

I am using LiveData. Max data file is about 1 - 3 MB.

I see, can you switch to Flow and observe it in a coroutineScope in your activity by calling lifecycleScope.launch { zebraViewModel.getAllZebra.collect{ } }
